# How to add elements to div dynamically in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, reactive-programming

i am very new to react .. Please if somebody can help me.

i have received the data from web service in json format and have in array.
so the data received is like : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mexPH.jpg)
Now what i want is in front it should create a screen as :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX2ld.jpg)

How to create a div of this kind . Because this div has to be generated dynamically as there could he another web service called which would be generating some other fields or would have more fields.

My code snippet :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nd2b.jpg)

UI like this (just the labels be different labels here would be dbname, profilename,username as this is what i am receiving from Data)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVZs.jpg)

Comment: can you share code and may be a screenshot of UI that you're trying to create?

Comment: Hi i have added my code as well as sample structure how it should look in UI.

Comment: You need some information in this like what type of element it should be. You can either maintain map of all the possible fields with their element types or it would be easy if service provides that info.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can just use an element of other JSX-Elements in other JSX Elements.

Let's imagine we have a DatabaseList Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const DatabaseList = ({ data }) => { // data is the json you got from the server (array of databases)
  const databases = data.map(db => <Database name={db.name} profilename={db.profilename} password={db.password} key={db.name} />);

  // databases is now an array of JSX-Elements. We can just return that array here to get it displayed. Don't forget to set the key to an unique value (e.g. database name)
  return <div>{databases}</div>;
}

export default DatabaseList;
```

And of course the Database component that just takes the name etc. as props and then displays it. If you want to change the data later you need to implement something like an onChange event to your database component.

If you need help on how to write the database component let me know or share your code and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Pooja, would you mind pasting the code as a snippet. It would be easier for us to help you.